# How to reuse for loop methods with same parameters

Tags: for-loop, recursion, foreach, reusability, coding-efficiency

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    for(SomeClass Object:Sample) {
        Output=method1(Object);
    }
}
```

I have sorting methods named method1,method2,method3,method4,method5 with same parameters and same return type .how to use all sorting methods in this loop efficiently

Comment: please add the methods that you describe under your code

Comment: if ( object.contains(something){
 list.add(object);  }

Comment: but the if conditions are different